# How to remove default spacing between textviews android

Tags: android

Answer ::: Used `android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"` for both TextView 3 and 4.

I have two linear layouts(horizontal) with two textviews each.

TextView1     TextView2

TextView3     TextView4

I get a default spacing between these LinearLayouts, which i don't want. I want the textviews 3 and 4 appear right below the 1 and 2. How do I get it?

The outer layout is a relative layout

XML

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/img"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imp"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="@string/xyzs"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:gravity="left" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/impr"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="@string/xyz2"
        android:textColor="#545454"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="right" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/v"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="@string/xyz3"
        android:textColor="#747474"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:gravity="left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vo"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="@string/xyz4"
        android:textColor="#545454"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: then use relative layout

Comment: try removing the gravity attributes from the TextViews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using negative margin on TextView 3 and TextView 4.

```
android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
```